# Enlarging ubuntu partition after installation

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 installed on same hard drive on different partitions.
Windows has about 550GB and Ubuntu only 50GB.

I had installed Ubuntu just to test for first so I chose this quite limited partition size.

I tried on Windows shrinking the partition of Windows, no problems with that.

But, if I expand the Ubuntu partition for instance with GParted, will it cause data loss?
Does it just smoothly increase the size of Ubuntu partition or corrupt all the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enlarging the partition with gparted will not cause data loss.

Of course, you do have a back-up, just in case, right?